# Run a shell script on a screen in parallel and serially at the same time

Tags: python, bash, shell, parallel-processing, gnu-screen

I have 3 commands I want to run within a shell script within a GNU screen.

The following is the content from `script.sh`.

```
counter=$((counter + 1))
screen -dmS $counter sh -c \
"command1;exec bash;\
python3 script2.py ${word};exec bash &&\
command3;exec bash"
```

When I run `./script.sh`. I want to run command1 first, then python3 script2. I only want to run command3 after python3 script2 is done.

I want to be able to open the screen and check on the python3 script2 process until it finishes that's why I'm doing it this way.

But I can see that command 1 and command 3 are being run simultaneously.

What's the right way to do this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is "," between python3 script2.py ${word} and exec bash . it will execute *exec bash* without waiting for the completion of script2.

*exec bash* will complete immediately and *invoke command 3* before the completion of *script2*

I have made following change

```
"command1 ; exec bash;\
python3 script2.py ${word} && exec bash ;\
command3;exec bash"
```